# HTML,CSS How do i prevent the expand/show from hiding/collapsing

Tags: html, css

hello how do i prevent the content from collapsing/hiding when i click on Content 1 or 2

```css
.details,
.show,
.hide:target {
  display: none;
  color: black;
}

.hide:target+.show,
.hide:target~.details {
  display: block;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a id="hide1" href="#hide1" class="hide">+ Content</a>
<a id="show1" href="#show1" class="show">- Content</a>
<div class="details">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Content1">Content1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Content2">Content2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't, because that is not really possible using this kind of technique. As soon as you click one of those links, `.hide:target` won't apply any more, _because_ you clicked a link pointing somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.hide {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hide::before {
  content: '+ Content';
  display: block;
}

.hide::after {
  content: '- Content';
  display: none;
}

.details  {
  display: none;
  transition:all 0.4s linear;
}

input:checked ~ .details,
input:checked + .hide::after {
  display: block;
}

input:checked + .hide::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" style="visibility:hidden">
<label for="toggle" class="hide"></label>
<div class="details">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Content1">Content1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Content2">Content2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tags reload the pages and thus the main div is collapsing.
You can either use this.

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Content1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Content2</a></li>
```

Or if you still want to use href then return false on click which will prevent it from reloading the page.

```
<li><a href="#Content1" onclick="return false;">Content1</a></li>
<li><a href="#Content2" onclick="return false;">Content2</a></li>
```

Comment: _"Anchor tags reload the pages and thus the main div is collapsing"_ - that is not the _cause_ of the problem here though. These anchors only refer to an element within the current document, so there is not reload happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with target is that it disappears from the content +/- when the user clicks on something else.

To remember whether the content + or - has been clicked you can use a checkbox.

If you make the +/- content into labels instead of divs then they can be associated with the checkbox (using for=) and you can hide the actual checkbox.

```css
#showhide {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

#showhide~#show {
  display: block;
}

#showhide:checked~#show {
  display: none;
}

#showhide~#hide {
  display: none;
}

#showhide:checked~#hide {
  display: block;
}

#showhide~.details {
  display: none;
}

#showhide:checked~.details {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="showhide" type="checkbox">
<label for="showhide" id="show">+ Content</label>
<label for="showhide" id="hide">- Content</label>
<div class="details">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Content1">Content1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Content2">Content2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```